# Retrieve source files from git

Tags: xcode, git, file-recovery

I've been saving all my source files using the xcode git repository. I saw some articles online about speeding up the Mac performance and I used a tool called 'Monolingual' to cleanup unwanted language files on the hard drive. Unfortunately this also deleted my entire user directory along with all my source code.

Is there any way to retrieve the files from the local git? When i try to view them from xcode organizer, it doesn't show the previous saved repositories

Answer (score 0):

The question is: did it remove also the `.git` directory which contains your code history?

If yes, then you need to restore (from a time machine backup for instance) at least that directory, in order to be able to checkout again your working tree from that git repo.

Comment: where would this folder be located ?

Comment: @IphoneDeveloper in the root directory of your project, which means I suspect it is gone too.